# adding up perspective values in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, generics

I'm trying to add two different dictionary sets (same keys, different values)

mcdonalds_sausage_mcgriddle = {'calories': 550, 'fat': 33, 'carbs': 44, 'protein': 19}
fairlife_choc_milk = {'calories': 140, 'fat': 5, 'carbs': 13, 'protein': 13}

bkfast = int(float(mcdonalds_sausage_mcgriddle)) + int(float(fairlife_choc_milk))

print(bkfast)

I end up getting this error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'**

**This is my desired output:
{'calories': 690, 'fat': 38, 'carbs': 57, 'protein': 32}**

Answer (score 0):

Use a comprehension to build the new dictionary:

```
>>> mcdonalds_sausage_mcgriddle = {'calories': 550, 'fat': 33, 'carbs': 44, 'protein': 19}
>>> fairlife_choc_milk = {'calories': 140, 'fat': 5, 'carbs': 13, 'protein': 13}
>>> {k: v + fairlife_choc_milk[k] for k, v in mcdonalds_sausage_mcgriddle.items()}
{'calories': 690, 'fat': 38, 'carbs': 57, 'protein': 32}
```

If you have an arbitrary number of dicts a better approach would be to iterate over your list of dicts and accumulate the totals in a new dict:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> breakfast = defaultdict(int)
>>> for food in [mcdonalds_sausage_mcgriddle, fairlife_choc_milk]:
...     for k, v in food.items():
...         breakfast[k] += v
... 
>>> breakfast
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'calories': 690, 'fat': 38, 'carbs': 57, 'protein': 32})
```

Comment: appreciate ya Samwise. Noticed that you listed 'for k, v in food.items():
breakfast[k] += v'. I do indeed have an arbitrary # of dicts. How could I modify this part of the code to accomodate these dicts (about 75 items atm)

Comment: The code you're talking about addresses that exact situation.  It iterates over each dict (all the items in all the dicts that you provide to `for food in ...`)  in its entirety.

Comment: Understood. tysm